# How do I clone Input fields without messing up unique ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input form attached with an element that changes its children's properties. It just so happens that I need this element to be duplicable/cloned along with its input form. I am duplicating this element using `element.cloneNode(true)`

This isn't working because the inputs are radio buttons, etc with unique IDs. Is there a way to still have labels and input fields working fully while being able to clone them? Using vanilla javascript would be optimal but any suggestions will be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You'll want to make an attempt and  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can use conventions like first form id's must end with _1 and so on ...

Comment: @decpk Sorry to disagree, but I don't think this problem needs a tiny code snippet to explain. I am simply asking how to get around cloning input fields/forms without intruding on their ID property.

Comment: You may also consider why you need IDs in the first place if elements are dynamically generated. I think IDs are often abused for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an increment number on each label/id.

Here's an example:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.clone-container')
container.querySelectorAll('.clone-me').forEach((item, index) => {
  // Clone it
  let cloned = item.cloneNode(true)
  
  // Add an increment number to label and input (so it's unique)
  cloned.querySelector('label').setAttribute('for', `anything${index}`)
  cloned.querySelector('input').setAttribute('id', `anything${index}`)
  
  // Append
  container.append(cloned)
})
```

```html
<div class="clone-container">
  <div class="clone-me">
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="option1" name="options">
  </div>
  <div class="clone-me">
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="option2" name="options">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `contentedible="true"` on the element you can avoid inputs entirely and hence no need for IDs. As for the radio buttons you can also avoid inputs by adding "onClick" event listeners that add a selected class.

Comment: Interesting. Leave a sample code if you can !